# Lenovo T410 overheats since replacing HDD with SSD hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cpu, hardware-failure, overheating

As already mentioned in the title, my Lenovo T410 notebook overheats regularly since I've replaced my old harddisk with a SSD harddisk.

My assumption is that the CPU is stressed since replacing the harddisk and more information processes the core in the same time.

I'm using Windows 7 and updated every possible driver. It's a clean installation, just re-installed my computer last night.

If I reuse my old harddisk in the same notebook, it seems that no overheating is happening. At least my computer does not suddenly shut down or crash.

How can I increase the CPU fan under Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working from a fresh install of Windows, don't forget to download and install all the drivers from Lenovo, most importantly (for this) the [Power Management drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS014939).  Once they are in installed you should be able to either manually clock your CPU back (as you did) or the laptop should be able to automatically throttle the CPU as it needs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same thing happen to me when I replaced the disk in my t500 with a SSD. 
My fix was to use a can of compressed air to blow the first out of my laptop. I paid particular attention to the CPU vents on the side and down through the top of the keyboard. I have not had a problem since cleaning the laptop.